# Arithmetic operations using numbers from grep

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have `FILE` from which I can extract two numbers using `grep`. The numbers appear in the last column.

```
 $ grep number FILE 
 number1:    123
 number2:    456
```

I would like to assign the numbers to variables, e.g. `$num1` and `$num2`, and do some arithmetic operations using the variables.

How can I do this using bash commands?

Comment: Output is exactly " number1:    123
 number2:    456
"?

Comment: @Alireza The numbers vary depending on inputs. They can be floats. But the form of the output is always the same.

Comment: Is "number1: " is part of output?

Comment: @Alireza Yes. That is the bash command I used and the terminal output of the command.  I grep "number". Then of course lines including "number" are grepped.

Comment: will it always be exactly 2 numbers? or could the number of entries vary?

Comment: Can you add some of your input to your question?

Comment: @markp-fuso There are always 2 numbers. Only values of the numbers can vary depending on `FILE`. That is, the command line output of `$ grep number FILE2` can be two lines: `number1:    3.14` for the first line and `number2:    2.1511113` for the second line.

Comment: Regarding `I would like to assign the numbers to variables, e.g. $num1 and $num2, and do some arithmetic operations using the variables.` - it's **extremely** unlikely that that's a good idea vs just using awk to both find the numbers and do the arithmetic. Post a new question if you'd like help with whatever it is you're doing.

Comment: @EdMorton I agree. `grep` is redundant. Could you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69330245/extract-numbers-from-a-text-file-and-do-arithmetic-operations)?

Comment: I did but I see you already accepted the first answer you got so no point me looking any more now.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of a number of “dynamic variable names” questions. For example, my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68864790/8584929) provides all the syntax examples needed for both associative arrays and dynamic variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- we want to match on lines that **start with** the string `number`
- we will always find 2 matches for `^number` from the input file
- not interested in storing values in an array

Sample data:

```
$ cat file.dat
number1: 123
not a number: abc
number: 456
```

We'll use `awk` to find the desired values and print all to a single line of output:

```
$ awk '/^number/ { printf "%s ",$2 }' file.dat
123 456
```

From here we can use `read` to load the variables:

```
$ read -r num1 num2 < <(awk '/^number/ { printf "%s ",$2 }' file.dat)

$ typeset -p num1 num2
declare -- num1="123"
declare -- num2="456"

$ echo ".${num1}.${num2}."
.123.456.
```

**NOTE:** periods added as visual delimiters

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to extract the numbers from the file. Assuming that the file is always in the format stated, then you can use a while loop, combined with the the `read` command to read the numbers into a named variable, one row at a time.

You can then use the `$((  ))` operator to perform integer arithmetic to keep a running total of the incoming numbers.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i total=0           # -i declares an integer.

while read discard number; do # read returns false at EOF. discard is ignored.
  total=$((total+number))     # Variables don't need '$' prefix in this case.
done < FILE                   # while loop passes STDIN to the 'read' command.

echo "Total is: ${total}"
```

Comment: Please read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some of the reasons not to do this.

Comment: Of course. If you want performance, or robustness, or many other attributes described in that article, then Bash is not your answer. However, the OP explicitly asked for a Bash solution.

Comment: As is extremely common, when the OP asked for bash commands they certainly didn't mean only bash builtins, they just want commands they can call from bash such as awk as included in their tags.

Comment: Perhaps you are right. Perhaps not. Only the OP can confirm that. It is my preference to use built-ins over child processes when possible, especially when readability is not affected.

Comment: That's fine but when it requires a shell read loop as in this case the result will be extremely slow, fragile, complicated, nonportable, etc. Consider what you posted vs `awk '{total+=$2} END{print total+0}' FILE` which is obviously more concise, would run orders of magnitude faster and would work as-is in every shell on every Unix box. Just something to consider.