# Extract numbers from a text file and do arithmetic operations

Tags: bash, awk

After a program is finished, I obtain an output file(`FILE`) containing two consecutive lines including the word "number".

```
...some texts...
number1    3.145
number2    1.56
...some texts...
```

Only the two lines in `FILE` contain "number". The values vary depending on the input file for the calculation. Sometimes the program prints values in scientific notation like `6.145E-03`.

What I would like to do is extract the two values from the two lines and do some arithmetic operations using bash commands. For example, say the two values are `$num1` and `$num2`, `10*($num1 + $num2)/($num1 - $num2)`.
I think `awk` has an answer to this question.

---

p.s.

If not considering scientific notation leads a much simpler answer, I would try that solution. Scientific notation appears only some special cases which can be neglected.

Comment: could you be a bit more specific on what the current issue is? in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69329025) you accepted an answer for etracting those numbers into a pair of `bash` variables ... but this question is asking, again, how to extract the values ... **plus** how to do math; if the question is simply how to do the math ... consider updating the question to remove all references to extracting data and just provide the current contents of the variables ... followed up by the type of math operations you're trying to accomplish

Comment: as you're probably finding out ... `bash` doesn't 'do math' when it comes to anything other than integers; for dealing with floats/reals/scientific-notation/etc you'll need to look at other options, eg, `bc`, `awk`, `matlab(?)`, `python`, `perl`, etc ... but which tool to use is going to depend heavily on knowing the exact types of 'math' you're trying to perform, which means providing more details on your actual requirements (showing inputs, your attempted code, and the desired output)

Comment: @markp-fuso [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69329406/9094625) perfectly works for my problem and I already wrote a script for the problem. This new questions is more like a learning purpose of `awk` as I agree with @Ed Morton's comment on the question.

Comment: @markp-fuso For the math part, I could manage using `bc -l`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arithmetic operations using numbers from grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69329025/arithmetic-operations-using-numbers-from-grep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the sole purpose of this question is to use `awk` to parse a file and perform some math on the values extracted from the file ...

Same assumptions as from the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69329025):

- we want to match on lines that start with the string `number`
- we will always find 2 matches for `^number` from the input file
- if there are more than 2 matches for `^number` said matches will be ignored

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
/^number/  { num[++i]=$2 }
END        { print (10 * (num[1] + num[2]) / (num[1] - num[2]) ) }
' file.dat
```

This generates:

```
-17.3874
```

For changing the output format we can use standard `printf` formats, eg:

```
awk '
/^number/  { num[++i]=$2 }
END        { printf "%.2f\n", (10 * (num[1] + num[2]) / (num[1] - num[2])) }
' file.dat
```

This generates:

```
-17.39
```

**NOTE:** - if there are any concerns about the reliability of the input data OP can add sanity checks (eg, on the matching lines is field #2 (`$2`) actually a number? what to do if `num[1] - num[2]` == `0` leads to a 'divide by 0' error?)